# How to replace Ip Address for peer-to-peer connection for media in WebRTC app?

Tags: webrtc

I am writing WebRTC application for windows. My scenario is like:

1. LAN is default network interface for all applications.
2. System has more than one network interfaces like LAN and Wifi or usb modem.
3. WebRTC Signaling should use LAN & media (peer-to-peer connection) should use Wifi network. So that application can get fast network access for media communication.

Question- How to replace the Wifi Ip Address from LAN IP Address for media 
communication (peer-to-peer connection)?

My observation is:

1. It is possible to print Private and Public ICE candidates as per blow code.

   ```
   pc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {
     if (evt.target.iceGatheringState == "complete") {
       local.createOffer(function(offer) {
         console.log("Offer with ICE candidates: " + offer.sdp);
         signalingChannel.send(offer.sdp);
    });
   ```

This code prints below info in my case.
Private ICE candidate (192.168.1.73:60834) for the peer
Public ICE candidate (50.76.44.100:69834) returned by the STUN server.

Now how to replace the Private ICE conditate (IP Address) to Wifi (IP Address)?
Could you please suggest any solution?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have two active interfaces and you want to force applications to use one over the other? On windows, you can change which interface is utilized by default fairly easily(through OS settings), though I am not sure you can do it through the browser.

Comment: Yes it is very difficult to change it in browser. There is work around, I got, sharing here. Use below tool that can solve some problem  http://geekyadmins.com/how-to-use-forcebindip-on-windows-7/